# Alternative to Oracle Apex get_callback_url() for social login redirect handling?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, callback, apex

The Ebay API provides an OAUTH2 flow that I was able to setup with Apex's social login authentication scheme. However, ebay doesn't allow the callback/success URL to be defined in the call. Instead, the url is defined in the eBay API developer's panel and is identified in the call by an "runame".

The callback url returned by `apex_authentication.get_callback_url()` exceeds eBay's character limit. The base application url is already long since I am running off an Always Free OCI instance. Add in the ajax ID and page ID and there's no way to get it under 250 characters.

What alternatives can I pursue to get a shorter URL to provide ebay to redirect after login success?

I tried building my own callback page with an apex redirect dynamic action but could not get it to redirect. I'm also worried I will miss something important to security and leave a vulnerability with this approach.

I've also considered getting a custom domain name to shorten the URL.